# External monitor fails to connect

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Issue: After coming back from months of homeoffice, my external monitor does not work anymore with my regular setup. It simply stays dark when connecting my laptop and it is also not recognized from Ubuntu. I connect the monitor using Displayport and a docking station (Lenovo UltraDock) to my laptop (Thinkpad T460s). Pre homeoffice, this exact same setup worked, at home I connect directly to my external monitor using HDMI which works.
The external display is not recognized in the Ubuntu display settings, or in xrandr.

So far I tried the following, replacing the docking station with another UltraDock, exchanging the Displayport cable, using instead a Displayport to HDMI cable and reinstalling the displaylink driver. All of which did not result in a success. I only managed to connect the monitor using a DVi to HDMI adapter and connecting a HDMI cable directly to the laptop. But then the I couldn't select a resolution higher than 1280x720. The monitor worked on a MacBookAir, connecting it using a Displayport to Displayport Mini adapter.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this, or further debug it?

Displaylink-driver: 5.6.0-59.176

```bash
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
```

```bash
xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   2560x1440     60.00*+  48.00    59.95
   1920x1440     60.00
   1856x1392     60.01
   1792x1344     60.01
   2048x1152     59.90    59.91
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95
   1920x1080     59.97    59.96    59.93
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
   1600x1024     60.17
   1400x1050     59.98
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1280x960      60.00
   1440x810      60.00    59.97
   1368x768      59.88    59.85
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
   1152x864      60.00
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
   1024x768      60.04    60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.05
   896x672       60.01
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
   960x600       59.93    60.00
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
   840x525       60.01    59.88
   864x486       59.92    59.57
   800x512       60.17
   700x525       59.98
   800x450       59.95    59.82
   640x512       60.02
   720x450       59.89
   700x450       59.96    59.88
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x405       59.51    58.99
   684x384       59.88    59.85
   680x384       59.80    59.96
   640x400       59.88    59.98
   576x432       60.06
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
   512x384       60.00
   512x288       60.00    59.92
   480x270       59.63    59.82
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   432x243       59.92    59.57
   320x240       60.05
   360x202       59.51    59.13
   320x180       59.84    59.32
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "does not work" and what, if anything, you have tried to fix it. Specifically: What does the monitor display? Does it show up in the Ubuntu display settings? Does it work on a different computer? Does it work if connected directly without the intervening docking station?

Answer (score 1):

My company has experienced this with several models of Lenovo x1s.  The fix has been to do the emergency reset by pushing the pinhole at the bottom of the laptop for 30 seconds and then powering the laptop back on.  Don't know if your Lenovo has the pinhole as well, but give it a shot.  Just looked up the affected models but yours isn't one of them, but maybe try it anyway?  Lenovo support said to ensure you have your Bitlocker key available in case it asks for it but none of my users have ever been asked.

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht508988

Comment: If I could upvote twice, I would